# Как добавить записи (примерно несколько сотен) в две связанные таблицы в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, insert, autoincrement

Нужно взять записи из таблицы journal и добавить в таблицу themes, в которой  themeID PRIMARY_KEY AUTO_INCREMENT. После этого нужно добавить данные в таблицу assigned_students, так же в этой таблице есть поле themeID, в нее должна записываться LAST_INSERT_ID() из таблицы themes. Связь таблиц themes и assigned_students ОДИН К ОДНОМУ. Моя реализация выглядит так:

```
  DELIMITER $$

  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_rows $$

  CREATE PROCEDURE insert_rows()
    BEGIN
      DECLARE lastID INT DEFAULT 0;

      WHILE lastID <= 268 DO
        INSERT INTO themes (tutorID, year, theme_name, degreeID)
        SELECT tutorID, year, work_name, degreeID from journal;
        SET lastID = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
        INSERT INTO assigned_students (studentID, tutorID, themeID, writing_language_id, work_typeID)
        SELECT studentID, tutorID, lastID, 0, 4 from journal;
      END WHILE;
    END;

    DELIMITER $$

    CALL insert_rows();
```

Но данный код не правильно работает, так как SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() возвращает ID только первой добавленной записи, а не каждой записи. И получилось будто связь в двух новых таблицах ОДИН КО МНОГИМ.

Comment: это невозможно сделать не видя данные. приведите точную структуру входной таблицы, пример данных и как они должны лечь в выходные таблицы. А вообще подозреваю, что last_insert_id совершенно ни к чему, потому что после вставки записей в первую таблицу, во втором запросе можно делать join только что вставленных данных с исходными, получая нужные id. А еще крайне странным выглядит что вы пытаетесь вставить одинаковое количество записей в обе таблицы, как будто у вас связь один к одному

Comment: *Нужно взять записи из таблицы journal и добавить в таблицу themes* По какому критерию брать записи?

Comment: получается нужно взять все данные из таблицы journal (сейчас там около 300 записей) и разделить по двум таблицам. Связь в двух новых таблицах действительно один к одному

Comment: ну если один к одному то тогда точно без всяких циклов один раз вставляем данные в первую таблицу, а при вставке во вторую используем `select ... from journal j join themes t on t.tutorID=j.tutorID` Только над условием соединения конечно поработать, потому что вы даже не указали какой уникальный ключ в таблице journal

Comment: Если в таблице `journal` набор (комбинация) полей `(tutorID, year, work_name, degreeID)` уникален - задача тривиальна (см. выше). Если же нет - то всё немного сложнее, и оптимальное решение зависит от версии сервера